# Jackson serialize and deserialize objects without double quotes

Tags: serialization, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I want to serialize and deserialize objects like java `Date` or `UUID` to and from String.
The problem is that it surrounds the String itself with double quotes:

```
String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(date);
System.out.println("String: @@" + s + "@@"); // String: @@"2017-12-06T04:50:30Z"@@
...
Date d = objectMapper.readValue(s, Date.class); // Expects the String to be "\"2017-12-06T04:50:30Z\""
```

Is there a way to configure the object mapper to not use/expect the redundant double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem: I didn't find any other way but an ugly workaround. I just remove/add the quotes to the string after/before passing it to the object mapper.

Comment: Yes, in my case I used  .replaceAll("\"", "")  to remove the extra escaped double-quotes.